# Well-conditioned pseudospectral for computing eigenvalues to (partial) differential equations

Tags: eigenvalues, differential-equations, pseudospectral

I am working on writing a Chebyshev pseudospectral method (see for example "[Chebsyhev and Fourier spectral methods](https://depts.washington.edu/ph506/Boyd.pdf)" by John Boyd) to solve for the eigenvalues of differential equations of the form

$ \left(a_2(x) \frac{d^2}{dx^2} + a_1(x)\frac{d}{dx} + a_0(x)\right)u - \lambda u = 0$

There are "regular" boundary conditions (i.e. $u$ should be regular on the boundary; see the edits below). Using Chebyshev pseudospectral methods I can turn the above differential equation into a matrix eigenvalue equation

$ Mu=\lambda u$

My problem is that the Chebyshev pseudospectral differentiation matrices are very poorly conditioned, e.g. the condition number of the pseudospectral matrix to $d^2/dx^2$ scales as $N^4$, where $N$ is the number of collocation points. This makes computing the eigenvalues to the operator $M$ numerically unstable when I use many collocation points, and I need to use many points to properly resolve rapidly oscillating eigenfunctions $u$.

I could apply a preconditioner matrix $P$ to $M$ to get a generalized eigenvalue equation

$PMu - \lambda Pu=0$

but I'm not sure that would actually make the eigenvalue solver more stable. Does anyone know applying a preconditioning matrix could make computing the eigenvalues more numerically stable? And if so, could they post several references that shows this is true/provides some examples?

EDITS:

- I'd like to consider equations where $a_2(x)$ could vanish at the boundaries (see third bullet point), so there are two choices of boundary conditions: "regular" and "irregular" boundary condtions. What is nice about using pseudospectral methods is that they naturally pick the "regular" solution. All of which is to say that I want to use pseudospectral methods to solve this ODE.
- The matrix M is not generally self-adjoint or symmetric for Chebyshev pseudospectral methods, so I'm not worried about losing that property in the system
- The functions $a_i(x)$ that I'm looking at are fairly complicated, but roughly they take the form

$a_2(x) = x^2(1-x)$

$a_1(x) = c_0 + c_1x + c_2x^2 + c_3x^3$

$a_0(x) = d_0 + d_1x + d_2x^2$

The coefficients $c_i,d_i$ are generally complex (not real).

- I don't need all of the eigenfunctions, but I would like to have more than the first few lowest one. To make things worse, I want to have high accuracy (say a relative error of $10^{-10}$ or so), so that is driving the need to have many Chebyshev coefficients even for the lower eigenmodes.

Comment: What about using a Finite Difference, Ritz or Finite Element method?

Comment: Is $M$ symmetric/selfadjoint? This is a property that would be lost with (one-side) preconditioning, together with realness of the eigenvalues.

Comment: The poor conditioning of spectral differentiation matrices is well known to those working on hydrodynamic stability. I have not seen the use of preconditioners to deal with this problem, and I'm not sure it's a suitable choice. I recommend looking at what people do for the Orr-Sommerfeld equation as a keyword to get you started.

Comment: You should try the finite-element spectral collocation method which is basically the same grid but multiple times. This leads to a good resolution while keeping the effects of the $N^4$ low. What concrete functions $a_k(x)$ do you use?

Comment: Is the goal to find all eigenmodes? Or finding just the lowest order eigenmode, or several, would be enough? Low order eigenmodes should not be very oscillatory.